# Neural network: how to normalize user behavior as input

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, normalization, modeling

I am working on a neural network project which reads server log files and tries to categorize users into `candidate buyers` and `random surfers` buckets.

The log file looks like

```
timestamp, user_id, event, page
1454973364, user_A, enter, http://some_url/?page=dashboard
1454973365, user_A, enter, http://some_url/?page=search&q=tablet
1454973366, user_A, enter, http://some_url/?page=faq&item=1234
1454973366, user_B, enter, http://some_url/?page=about_us
1454973366, user_A, enter, http://some_url/?page=order_placed
...
1454973368, user_A, exit, http://some_url/?page=order_placed
1454973368, user_B, exit, http://some_url/?page=about_us
```

All users like `user_A` should be **positively** targeted as `candidate buyers` and `user_B` should be **negatively** targeted and categorized as `random surfers`. Of course, the goal of my project is to make a prediction before the user hits the conversion page `order_placed`.

1. What is the best way to model series of events like this into inputs?
2. A more general question. From the log data we can obtain the info about how users engage our site (drag a widget, click a link, scroll down/up, time spent on page, etc.). Given an array of actions like these, what is the general approach in machine learning to model them as inputs?

Comment: Would you like to constantly feed your model with new data? New clicks, scrolls, search etc.? Do I correctly understand that initially you know nothing about the user and only through interaction with the web site you get features that allow you to make the classification?

Comment: One of the ways is to try predicting the category of each user based on the last N actions. Where you'll have to find a suitable N. This means that for each user, you'll have to feed the network N log items. Would this suite your application?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski I would say I do not constantly feed new data to the model. I already have tons of data and I am going to train the model based on the data I already have.

Comment: @Mido Yes it suites my application. The question is I am not sure how to quantify array of actions into neural network inputs.

Comment: @SpicyrentHouse one way of doing it is if you have 3 actions (drag, click, scroll) then each of them can be an input to the NN. That input should be 1 if that action happened and 0 otherwise. To represent more than one log entry, you'll have to repeat this. For the time input, you can find a way to normalize it to a value between 0 and 1.

Comment: @SpicyrentHouse New user appears on the web site, event "enter". How do you he will make a purchase? Don't you have to wait and observe the behaviour?

Comment: @Mido One issue with that approach is there will be thousands of input nodes. For example, the 'click' event can happen on any page, and there are thousands of possible links user can click on. If I create one node for each action+link combo, wouldn't this approach make my inputs very sparse?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski Well, I can tell a user made a purchase if he hits my 'conversion page': http://some_url/?page=order_placed.

Comment: @SpicyrentHouse you can create a node for each action and then find a way to enumerate the link. An option is to give each page a number and use the binary representation of that number. To make this more meaningful, you can represent the category of each page.